# PHP 5.6 DateTime Strict warning timezone UTC

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm currently getting following STRICT warning when creating a UTC datetime from php.

Strict Warning: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for 'UTC/0.0/no DST' instead

This is the line of code I'm using.

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', sprintf('%.6F', microtime(true)), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

The strange thing is I'm already using UTC as timezone, but it still outputs this warning. How can I get rid of this?

I'm running php 5.6 on Debian Wheezy.

All my php.ini files contain the following `date.timezone` setting.

`date.timezone = "Europe\Amsterdam"`

Comment: You're writing is wrong - `Europe/Amsterdam` (regular slash). If that didn't help, consider adding `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');` in that file (maybe the php.ini files you've edited are being ignored from some reason). Update me if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I had missed one php.ini file + including the fix (forward slash) as suggested by @Ofir-Baruch it seems to be solved.

The php.ini I forgot was the hhvm one.

It failed on console lines since I configured all console php to be executed by hhvm using following command.

`/usr/bin/update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /usr/bin/hhvm 60`

I forgot about that and figured that out when I echo'd following.

`echo phpinfo();` which returns `Hip Hop` in case of hhvm.